# Export / Backup emails on iPad (Locally only)

Tags: ipad, email, backup, mobile-mail

My email was hacked. The hacker deleted all the emails on the server and are unrecoverable.

I have the emails still sitting on my iPad which was originally connected through IMAP. I need to get these emails back.

How can I export these emails from my iPad locally without allowing a reconnection to the server (which would lose them all again)?

Edit: I have little experience with iPads in general. Are there are mail apps that I could download that would do a sync with the local emails that would then allow an export? (Clutching at straws here!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Connect and Sync your iPad with a Windows/Mac iTunes installed machine.
2. Create a backup.
3. Open the backup and find the mail folder.

The iPad mail client stores the emails as an SQLite database (at least it used to) so you should be able to use any SQLite client to open the same.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately the client took the decision to just delete the emails and start afresh. I will accept your answer though